# Reading values from file into array causes segmentation fault, C

Tags: c, file-io, malloc, scanf, scientific-notation

I have multiple data files with two columns of numbers in scientific format as shown below:

```
   -6.000000E-2 0.000000E+0
    1.060000E+0 0.000000E+0
    2.510000E+0 0.000000E+0
    2.700000E+0 5.000000E-2
    2.735000E+0 5.000000E-2
    2.755000E+0 1.000000E-1
    2.775000E+0 1.500000E-1
    2.785000E+0 1.500000E-1
    2.790000E+0 2.000000E-1
    2.805000E+0 2.500000E-1
    2.810000E+0 3.500000E-1
    2.815000E+0 4.000000E-1
    2.820000E+0 5.000000E-1
    2.825000E+0 5.500000E-1
    2.835000E+0 6.000000E-1
    2.835000E+0 7.000000E-1
    2.840000E+0 8.000000E-1
    2.840000E+0 9.000000E-1
    2.850000E+0 9.500000E-1
    2.850000E+0 1.050000E+0
    2.855000E+0 1.200000E+0
    2.860000E+0 1.300000E+0
    2.865000E+0 1.400000E+0
    2.870000E+0 1.450000E+0
    2.870000E+0 1.600000E+0
    2.875000E+0 1.650000E+0
    2.880000E+0 1.800000E+0
    2.880000E+0 1.900000E+0
    2.885000E+0 2.000000E+0
    2.885000E+0 2.150000E+0
    2.890000E+0 2.200000E+0
    2.895000E+0 2.300000E+0
    ...
```

The first column is the x-data, the second is the y-data. The columns are separated by a `<tab>` character. The number of lines in the file varies from 300 to 400. I wrote a program to read the values from the file and calculate the gradient using the 100th and 200th point. From that gradient i need to calculate the x-intercept (which i use the 150th point). This is the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float **make_array(int size);
void cleanup(float **array, FILE *filehandle);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    float **entry;  //2D array to hold data; entry[0][i] holds the x_i while entry[1][i] holds y_i.
    FILE *infile;
    infile=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(infile=NULL){
        printf("Unable to open inpufile");
        exit(1);
    }

    char c;
    int i, numlines=0, ret;

    //count number of lines in file
    while((c=(fgetc(infile))!=EOF))
        if(c=='\n')
            numlines++;
    printf("Number of lines: %d", numlines);

    //array to store values from file
    entry=make_array(numlines);
    rewind(infile);

    //read values into array, ensure correct number of arguments read
    for(i=0; i<numlines; i++){
        fscanf(infile, " %g\t%g\n", &entry[0][i], &entry[1][i]);
        if(ret!=2){
            printf("reading incorrect number of inputs from file.. Terminating");
            cleanup(entry,infile);
            exit(3);
        }
    }
    //dump array contents to screen to check
    for(i=0;i<numlines;i++)
        printf("%f\t%f\n", entry[0][i], entry[1][i]);

    //find gradient of the data between the 100th and 200th point
    float gradient = (entry[1][200]-entry[1][100])/(entry[0][200]-entry[0][100]);

    // use the 150th point (midpoint) and the gradient to calculate the x-intercept
    float vt = (entry[1][150]/gradient) - entry[0][150];
    printf("\n Threshold Voltage: %f\n", vt);

    cleanup(entry, infile);
return 0;
}

float **make_array(int size)
{   
    int i;
    float **entry = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
    if(entry==NULL) exit(2);
    entry[0] = malloc(size*sizeof(float));
    if(entry[0]==NULL) exit(2);
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) entry[0][i]==0.0;
    entry[1] = malloc(size*sizeof(float));
    if(entry[1]==NULL) exit(2);
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) entry[1][i]==0.0;
return entry;
}

void cleanup(float **array, FILE *filehandle)
{   free(array[0]);
    free(array[1]);
    free(array);
    fclose(filehandle);
}
```

The program compiles without errors or warning but produces a segmentation fault when executed (on Ubuntu Linux). I have been looking through this for quite sometime and still am unable to spot the problem. Any help/comments would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where does it crash when you run it in a debugger?

Comment: enable core dump, use gdb to find at which line or code was faulty. then you can narrow it down.

Comment: Rather than computing the gradient in the way you do, you could compute the full linear regression, which gives you slope and intercept based on the entire data set.

Answer (score 1):

```
float **entry = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
```

You want to `malloc(2*sizeof(float*))` there. Or better `malloc(2*sizeof *entry);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
float **entry = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
```

allocates the space of two `float` to store two `float *`. That will work, if on your platform `sizeof(float) == sizeof(float *)` is true. is it? Anyway it should be corrected.

Besides, the initialization `for(i=0; i<size; i++) entry[1][i]==0.0;` does nothing but compares uninitialized memory with 0.0.